# Looping through reading NetCDF and writing to csv

Tags: python, loops, netcdf

I'm new to python and trying to find netcdf files in a folder, extract data using a lat and lon for each file and then write the extracted data to a csv file and attaching information in the file name. I know it works for one file but I'm having trouble with the looping. Thanks

```
files = glob.glob(r'R:\Climate\Forecast\AccessS\AccessS_180830\evap\daily\*\*.nc')    

for file in files:

    ds = xr.open_dataset(file)
    evap_pos = ds.sel(lat=-38.2,lon=145.9,method='nearest').compute()
    evap_out = evap_pos['evap']
    #evap_out.plot()

    # get the extra information for filename
    Stdate= getattr(ds, 'source_data_start_date')  
    ensemble= getattr(ds, 'source_data_ensemble') 
    #print (FileID, ensemble)

    #write the csv file
    evap_csv = pd.Series(evap_out, index=ds['time']) 
    evap_csv.name = 'evap'
    evap_csv.to_csv('evapout' + Stdate + ensemble +'.csv', index=True, header=True)
```

Comment: What seems to be wrong with looping? Can you be more specific.

Comment: Python uses indentation levels to identify code blocks, e.g. what to execute within a for loop.  You are not showing indentation w/in your for loop so perhaps only the first file is processed.

Comment: @Eric Bridger: I assume the question is badly written in StackOverflow and actually everything after `for file in files:` has appeared in the loop. Otherwise there should have been `IndentationError: expected an indented block` as one cannot just have `for file in files:`

Comment: Thanks it did actually work it was just taking forever as the files were on an external site.

Answer (score 0):

you can use api to_dataframe().to_csv .